# How to ignore derived DbContext during EF4.3.1 Code First migration

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I am trying to use code-first migrations, but the project that contains my CustomContext also has a derived class, TracingCustomContext which I use when tracing the SQL generated:

```
DbContext => CustomContext => TracingCustomContext
```

The problem I have during code-first migrations is that when trying to run

```
Enable-Migrations
```

in Package Manager Console, this results in the (not unexpected) warning:

```
More than one class deriving from DbContext found in the current project.
Edit the generated Configuration class to specify the context to enable migrations for.
```

In order to get past this message and move on to Add-Migration -Initial, I had to comment out my TracingCustomContext class, then run Enable-Migrations.  The Configuration class that had been generated looked fine, so the suggestion in the warning didn't seem relevant.

So the question I have is whether there is any way to configure Migrations so it ignores a specific Context like TracingCustomContext? For example, an attribute to decorate the class, or a configuration setting somewhere?

Any ideas gratefully received.

Comment: I've written a blog post about my experience [getting started with Entity Framework code-first migrations](http://www.appetere.com/Blogs/SteveM/April-2012/Entity-Framework-Code-First-Migrations).  It includes the problem outlined here - hopefully I'll update it once I have more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the error message:

```
Edit the generated Configuration class to specify the context to enable migrations for.
```

Open the created Configuration.cs class (int the Migrations folder) and you will see:

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration</* TODO: put your Code First context type name here */>
```

Replace /* TODO: put your Code First context type name here */ with the type name of the context (do the same in the Seed method or remove the Seed method if you are not using it) and it should work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Pawel.  All sorted now. That'll teach me to ready the error messages more carefully!